# How to prove double negation elimination without using $\bot$?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, natural-deduction

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
I am trying to derive some rules without the use of the $\bot$ symbol.

First I want to describe how I am defining certain inference rules:

Negation Introduction: $\{(a\to b), (a \to \lnot b) \} \vdash \lnot a$:

$$\fitch{}
    {\fitch{a}
    {\vdots
    \\b}
    \\a\to b\\
    {\fitch{a}
    {\vdots
    \\\lnot b}}
\\ a \to \lnot b \\ \lnot a}$$

Now presume that we take the law of excluded middle $a \lor \lnot a$ as an axiom and use it (with negation introduction and disjunction elimination) to prove the double-negation rule:

$$\fitch{\lnot \lnot a}{
    a \lor \lnot a
    \\ \fitch{a}{
        a
    }
    \\ a \to a
    \\ \fitch{\lnot a}{
        \vdots
        \\ a
    }
    \\ \lnot a \to a
    \\ a \text{ (by or-elim using LEM and the two implications)}
}$$

I can't quite figure out how to fill in the dotted section. Normally we'd just restate $\lnot \lnot a$ and note the contradiction with $\lnot a$, state the contradiction $\bot$, and then use ex falso $\bot \to a$ to invoke $a$ and finish the proof.

But without the $\bot$ symbol, is this impossible to do? I don't know how to prove ex falso in the first place without using $\bot$ or double negation elimination which is the very thing I am trying to prove.

Comment: So are you using "proof by cases"? [That is, from p or q and p ->r and q -> r get r.] I mean is using this rule OK in your restricted system without $\bot$

Comment: @coffeemath yes that is allowed

Comment: Is *disjunctive syllogism* allowed?  You may use that instead.  $$\begin{split}\neg a \vdash \neg a\vee a\quad&\quad \neg a\vee a, \neg a \vdash a\\ \hline &\vdash \neg a \to a\end{split}$$

Comment: With $a \to b, a \to \lnot b \vdash \lnot a$ as $\lnot$-I rule, you may use $a, \lnot a \vdash b$ as $\lnot$-E rule.

Comment: If so, using $\lnot a \lor a$ and $\lor$-E, you may derive $\lnot \lnot a \vdash a$.

Comment: Oh!  Cutting out the middle man.   @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a falsum constant, your rule of *ex falso quodlibet* should look something like $\phi, \neg \phi \vdash \psi$.   So from the contradictory assumptions, $\neg\neg a$ and $\neg a$, you may immediately derive $a$.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{\neg\neg a}{\vdots\\\fitch{\neg a}{a \qquad \text{ex falso quodlibet  }\neg a, \neg\neg a \vdash a }\\\vdots}$$

---

**PS:** If *ex falso quodlibet* looks like $\phi\wedge\neg\phi\vdash\psi$, simply introduce a conjunction *then* use it.

---

**PPS**

If *ex falso quodlibet* is not accepted as fundamental, but *disjunctive syllogism* is, then introduce a disjunction and use that. $$\fitch{\neg\neg a}{\vdots\\\fitch{\neg a}{\neg a\vee a\qquad:\text{disjunctive introduction }\neg a\vdash \neg a\vee a\\a \qquad\qquad:\text{disjunctive syllogism }\neg a\vee a, \neg\neg a \vdash a }\\\vdots}$$

---

**P$^3$S**

Disjunctive Syllogism and Ex Falso Quodlibet are interprovable - each may be justified only by accepting the other - so which is considered fundamental by a proof system is a matter of preference.   (EFQ has a smaller format.)
 $$\tiny\fitch{((p\lor q)\land\lnot p)\to q:\text{Premise of Disj.Sylogism}}{\fitch{p\land\lnot p}{\lnot p:\text{Conj. Elim.}\\p:\text{Conj.Elim.}\\p\lor q:\text{Disj.Intro}\\(p\lor q)\land\lnot p:\text{Conj.Into.}\\q:\text{Cond.Elim.}}\\(p\land\lnot p)\to q:\text{Cond.Into}}\fitch{(p\land\lnot p)\to q:\text{Premise of Ex Falso Quodlibet}}{\fitch{(p\vee q)\land\lnot p}{\lnot p:\text{Conj.Elim.}\\p\lor q:\text{Conj.Elim.}\\\fitch{p}{p\land\lnot p:\text{Conj.Intro.}\\q:\text{Cond.Elim.}}\\p\to q:\text{Cond.Into.}\\\fitch{q}{}\\q\to q:\text{Cond.Intro.}\\q:\text{Disj.Elim.}}\\((p\vee q)\land\lnot p)\to q:\text{Cond.Into.}}$$

---

**P$^4$S**  Oh!    As Mauro comments, if $\phi\to\psi,\phi\to\neg \psi\vdash \neg \phi$ is considered as the negation introduction rule, then $\phi,\neg\phi\vdash\psi$ (EFQ) could be considered the corresponding negation elimination rule.   Thereby cutting out the need for a falsum symbol.

Comment: But does it require it's own rule or is it derivable?

Comment: *Ex falso quolibet* is a fundamental rule of natural deduction, though it is sometimes justified by accepting *disjunctive syllogism*.

Comment: I am trying to get a sense for which rules are derived and which aren't to see where the intuition for certain things come from. The idea of ex falso quodlibet is just a fundamental assumption? We can't prove it from other rules? Proving disjunctive syllogism appears to require double-negation elim. which is what I am trying to prove, for example.

Comment: Ex falso quodlibet and Disjunctive Syllogism are interprovable - each may be justified by accepting the other.  Which of them a N.D. proof system regards as more fundamental is just a matter of preference. @user525966

Comment: I think I've also seen formulations in which the rule you would use is $\lnot \phi \rightarrow \psi, \lnot \phi \rightarrow \lnot \psi \vdash \phi$.  (Sort of a combination of double negation elimination and negation introduction.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler That is Reduction to Absurdity (*reduction ad absurdum*, RAA), and yes, it is so. $$\dfrac{\dfrac{\neg \phi\to\psi~,~\neg\phi\to\neg\psi}{\neg\neg\phi}{\neg\mathsf I}}{\phi}{\neg\neg\mathsf E}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp What kind of notations are all of these here? Like when we do "$\varphi \vdash \psi$" style, versus the Fitch-style representation, versus those "fractional" looking things in your previous comment, versus a line-by-line like we often see with Hilbert-style systems? (should I make this its own question?)

Comment: @user525966 $\varphi, \varphi\to\psi\vdash \psi$ is a *sequent* notation meaning "$\varphi$ and $\varphi\to\psi$ syntatically entails $\psi$". The *natural deduction tree notation*, $\tfrac{\varphi\quad\varphi\to\psi}{\psi}$, indicates much the same, but lets us nest subproofs. Sometimes these presentations are combined to help keep track of assumptions made. The *fitch style* presentation, much like Hilbert-style, presents inferences as seperate lines, but includes subproofs by raising and discharging assumptions, as nested blocks. Search the site or raise another question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

[This prover is helpful to reply to this question. See example 3](https://www.vidal-rosset.net/sequent_calculus_prover_with_antisequents_for_classical_propositional_logic.html)